# How to execute a program under a linux live system?

Tags: linux

On my desktop computer with a Linux Mint-17-64bit distribution I've written a program in c++ with QT creator and I wanted to test it on my notebook (the relevant files are copied to the user directory). But this is running a Linux Mint-17-32bit...

So I took my bootable Linux Mint-17-64bit-USB pen drive to boot my notebook with that pen. I changed to the user directory of the notebook opened a terminal and tried ./Ins. But I got an error: Permission denied.
So I took a look at the permissions of the files which had user and group = 1000.
I changed user and group with `chown` to root and tried again. But again I got the error: Permission denied.

Comment: Running a x86-64 executable on a x86-32 system won't work, even with the correct permissions.

Comment: OP is using a **64bit live system**. This should work

Comment: Why don't you use a virtual machine? That allows you to use whatever architecture you want to test and you can install a system (or user a ready-to-use spanshot) instead of having to rely on a slow live system.

Comment: Can you add the output of `mount` and the output of `ls -al ./lns` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl : -rwx------ 1 root root 700253 May 26 18:12 and the output after ./Ins is bash: ./Ins: Permission denied

Comment: @arkascha : No, please, I do not like that. That it also the reason I'm using a dual-boot (Windows-Gaming / GNU/Linux-All others)

Comment: Em... nothing against your personal choice, but we are talking about testing some software here, aren't we? Why should a live system be better for that purpose? But OK, however you like...

Comment: @Earlybite Use `sudo ./lns` Isn't this obvious?

Comment: @arkascha There are valid reasons for testing on a different *hardware*. For example performance tests, or even functionality tests if the software depends on hardware features. However, I don't think anymore that those reasons apply here. ;)

Comment: @ arkascha : That is what I yet have. A 64bit desktop, a 32bit-notebook and a 64bit-usb boot pen. My thought was that a 64bit-boot pen would be enough to have a first look on my programm on another computer. By the way: My programm is using fork and an own IPC, so it might be a good look what happens on a very slow OS. And later I will install a 64bit-OS on my notebook...no VM.

Comment: Even the more a reason to use a virtual machine, sine you can configure the hardware to whatever test you want to perform... Slow or fast, different architecture, different hardware components, ...

Comment: and once more: if your notebook really is a 32bit system, then you cannot run a 64 bit live system on it. Something is fishy here...

Comment: @hek2mgl : OH, holy sh**! <shame over my head>
Honestly, thanks for your advice! Thanky you, sir.

Greeting Earlybite

Comment: @arkascha : ./Ins was running. Ok, the programm wasn't ending like on my 64bit-desktop, but that has other reasons. ./Ins was running...

Comment: To be more precise: you _cannot_ run a 64bit operating system on a 32bit hardware. It won't boot. So either your notebook has a 64bit architecture or that live stick runs a 32 bit system.

Comment: Ah, ok, the hardware... No problem. An Acer 6930g can handle 64bit. Thanks...

Comment: @Earlybite You are welcome. Please also have a look at [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/). This should work very well for you.